# python matplotlib curve graph change line color on a specific value question

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to know how to change `plot(a,b)` coordinates to `plot(a,b,color='red')` when the coordinates are above 40.0.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [20.5,30.2,35.4,40.2,25.2,41.5,24.3,24.1,40.2]
b = list(range(len(a)))

plt.plot(b,a,marker='x',color='blue')
plt.show()
```

I don't know how to know the position value when the plot draws, and I'd like to try another way, but I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: I just updated your tags. Please be careful which tags you choose; [tag:pylot] is something different than "pyplot", which doesn't have a specific tag (just use [tag:matplotlib].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To color the markers, you can create a color list that you pass to `plt.scatter` for the `c` parameter. I created the list using list comprehension. You didn't say how to handle the lines, so I just plotted them all as black in a separate plotting call.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

a = [20.5,30.2,35.4,40.2,25.2,41.5,24.3,24.1,40.2]
b = list(range(len(a)))
c = ["r" if value > 40 else "b" for value in a]

plt.plot(b, a, color="k")
plt.scatter(b, a, c=c, marker="x")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do I handle lines that exceed 40.0? c=[]It seems that the conditional specifies "r" and "b" color, and I understood that the scatter is distinguishing whether it is a mark or a color, but I have noticed the following error: ValueError: Provide either a 'c' argument or a 'color' kwarg, but not both. They are different, but their features overlap. It seems to me that my understanding is wrong.